# Excel formula to create a date range based upon one date that will be manually entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with creating the formula that will fill one cell with a date range. I manually enter the date (example: 8/19/18) and I need the calculation to give me 8/12/18 - 8/18/18.

Basically, I am entering the "issued date" and from that, I want the previous week's date range to be seen.

I know this isn't right ... but my basic skills would tell me it's something like: =(E8-7) - (E8-1)
where E8 would be the manually filled in date of 8/19/18

Thank you for any help or direction!

Comment: I agree with @BruceWayne's answer. Just further clarification, your formula `=(E8-7) - (E8-1)` will actually always evaluate to `-6` because dates in Excel are just numbers that are displayed as a date. You should read more about Excel's date numbering system for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close!  You need to use `TEXT()` to format in to the `mm/dd/yy` you want:

```
=TEXT((E8-7),"mm/dd/yy")&" - "&TEXT((E8-1),"mm/dd/yy")
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!! I knew it could be done and I just wasn't quite phrasing it right.